# How to find out what is pricing of Power Automate for old applications write in January - April 2020

Tags: power-automate, licensing, powerapps-canvas

When will the Power Apps Service Application become chargeable?

We read about Power apps that it will be free of charge for the next 5 years, when Premium Connectors will become part of the Pricing Plan.

Will the same happen with the Power Automate Service? Will it be free of charge, for now and change it's pricing plan after 5 years, counting from November 2019, too?

Please, if you could provide some assistance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, could you please post a link about where you read that the PowerApps Service will become chargeable after 5 years?
Some aspects of the service are chargeable ATM.

Second of all, PowerAutomate Premium Connectors require a premium license in order to function, not to mention that even an o365 license is require to execute a flow, so it's not free of charge.

I strongly advise you to watch over the Microsoft Docs and various PowerApps blogs in order to get the latest info about the service.